# AJAX Post values not received in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Below is my ajax file. Here I passed all my text box values.
And I post that values to edu.php. There I want to update two tables like details and test.

But nothing is updating in my database.While I checked the value with var_dump the string seems to be empty.But while passing from ajax I checked it with an alert it shows all the values in text box. So I believe problem is happening while posting from ajax to php.

**AJAX Code**

```
$('#edubackgroundsubmit').click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert("Hello");
  var per_email = $('#per_email').val();
  var master_overall = $('#master_overall').val();
  var master_pass_year = $('#master_pass_year').val();
  var master_college = $('#master_college').val();
  var master_univ = $('#master_univ').val();

  var data1 ="master_qual="+master_qual+"&master_overall="
  +master_overall+"&master_pass_year="+master_pass_year+"&master_college="+master_college+"&master_univ="+master_univ
  +"&edu_flag="+edu_flag;
  alert(data1);
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "edu.php?per_mobile="+per_mobile,
    dataString1: data1
  }).done(function( dataString1 ) 
          {
    alert(dataString1);
    $('#edu_alert').append(
      '<div class="alert alert-success text-center">' +
      '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">' +
      '&times;</button>' + dataString1 + '</div>');
  });
});
```

PHP File

```
if (isset($_POST['pass_year_12'])) {
    $pass_year_12 = $_POST['pass_year_12'];
} else {
    $pass_year_12 = "";
}
$l1   = "UPDATE test
    SET  edu_flag='$edu_flag'
        WHERE  per_mobile='$per_mobile'";
$l2   = "UPDATE details
    SET master_qual='$master_qual',
        master_overall='$master_overall',
        master_pass_year ='$master_pass_year ',
        master_college='$master_college'
       WHERE per_mobile='$per_mobile'";
$exec = mysqli_query($link, $l1);
if (mysqli_query($link, $l2)) {
  echo "Education Details Updated Successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($link);
}
```

Comment: what is `dataString1`???

Comment: replace dataString1 with only data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong. What's this bit:

```
dataString1: data1
```

You need to change it as:

```
data: data1
```

The function [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajax/) `POST`s only those given in the `data` attribute.

Comment: Hi @Praveen, one question from my side. User is passing URL like `url: "edu.php?per_mobile="+per_mobile`. So, according to URL it's GET.  And, he used `type:"POST",` So, `per_mobile` we have to access it through GET and rest all data which is passed in `data: data1` will be accessed by POST. Am i right ?

Comment: Sorry.Mistakenly i changed that

Comment: @KavyaBabu No problem... `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your code is hat you are sending the data at edu.php?per_mobile

so you need to add isset condition before the code... like this

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['per_mobile'])){ //write your code here }
```

and also replace datastring to data.
and then try.

Hope it may help.

For instance you can also use jQuery get or post method, that is more reliable and easy to learn.